# Confidence interval for variances

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, variance, chi-squared-test, matlab

I have a lot of variances $\sigma^2(x)$ as these:

[image: An example of my variances]

Now I have two task: remove the vertical outliers and compute the confidence intervals (for all cases, this is only one case).

I think that their distribution is the Chi-squared, so I have computed the confidence intervals in this way (I use the usually $\alpha = 0.05$ and $D_F = 99$):

$$U = \frac{D_F\sigma^2}{\chi^2_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}}=0.0076$$

$$L = \frac{D_F\sigma^2}{\chi^2_\frac{\alpha}{2}}=0.0043$$

As you can see these are results of experimental data. The problem is that $\min(\sigma^2(x))=0.0187$ and no one of these variances is in this range $[L ~~~ U]$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The standard $\chi^2$ distribution has mean equal to the number of degrees of freedom (and variance double that). When you look at your data, do you still believe the distribution should be $\chi^2$? Perhaps you should do some scaling first.

Comment: Of course. I have $N = 100$ variances, so I have $D_F = N-1=99$. Is it right?

Comment: And about of: "When you look at your data, do you still believe the distribution should be $\chi^2$?", I have try with the normal distribution (because I have a lot of variances), but sometimes I have the lower confidence interval negative.

Comment: The sample size is not related to the distribution of individual points in the sample. If you have an i.i.d. sample of $\chi^2(1)$ random variables, it does not matter whether you have 10, 100 or 1000 sample points; the distribution of each individual sample point remains $\chi^2(1)$